# C# StreamReader Always receives null using StreamSocketListener

Tags: c#, uwp

I tried to make a little test in C#, but it doesn't seems to work and honestly I cannot understand why.
The experiment is this. I write some strings in a list, then I start two threads: T1 the sender and T2 the receiver. T1 reads the strings I inserted before, and then sends them through the StreamWriter which is read by T2. At the end of the process, T2 returns what it did read, and the program terminates.
T1 seems to work fine: it sends the data, then closes the connection. T2 seems to receive the connection, but it doesn't read: the first reading is always null.

Anyone could help me pls?

Here's my code:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Storage;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;

namespace UWPConsoleApp
{
    class UWPConsoleApp
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<String> toSend = new List<string>();
            bool end = false;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please write something to send to the other task (write ';;;' to end)");
                string s = Console.ReadLine();
                if (s != ";;;")
                {
                    toSend.Add(s);
                    Console.WriteLine($"The list now contains {toSend.Count} lines");
                }
                else
                {
                    if(toSend.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("WARNING: you may insert atleast one line before going on");
                        continue;
                    }
                    end = true;
                }
            }
            while (!end);

            List<string> received;
            Task[] tasks =
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
                {
                    ThreadSender ts = new ThreadSender();
                    ts.buffer = toSend;

                    Console.WriteLine("(T1) waiting before starting...");
                    Thread.Sleep(7500);

                    ts.SendInfos();
                } ),
                Task.Factory.StartNew( async () =>
                {
                    ThreadReceiver tr = new ThreadReceiver();
                    received = await tr.ReceiveInfos();
                } )
            };

            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class ThreadSender
    {
        // buffer di invio
        public List<String> buffer;

        // socket per l'invio dei dati
        private StreamSocket ss;

        public ThreadSender()
        {
            buffer = new List<string>();
            ss = new StreamSocket();
        }

        public async void SendInfos()
        {
            HostName hn = new HostName("localhost");
            await ss.ConnectAsync(hn, "3000");

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ss.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite());
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ss.InputStream.AsStreamForRead());

            Console.WriteLine($"(T1) Sending line count: {buffer.Count}");
            sw.WriteLine(buffer.Count.ToString());
            foreach(string line in buffer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("(T1) sending line: {0}", line);
                sw.WriteLine(line);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("(T1) closing connection");
            ss.Dispose();
            ss = null;
        }
    }

    class ThreadReceiver
    {
        // buffer di scrittura
        public List<String> buffer = new List<string>();

        private StreamSocketListener ssl;
        private bool received = false;
        private bool error = false;

        public ThreadReceiver()
        {
            ssl = new StreamSocketListener();
        }

        public async Task<List<string>> ReceiveInfos() 
        {
            ssl.ConnectionReceived += onConnectionReceived;
            await ssl.BindServiceNameAsync("3000");

            Console.WriteLine("(T2) waiting for connections...");
            while (!received)
            {
                if(error)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("(T2) closing connection (error occurred)");
                    return null;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(2500);
            }

            return buffer;
        }

        public async void onConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("received a incoming connection");
            Thread.Sleep(2500);

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead());
            string receivedCountString = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
            if(receivedCountString == null)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("(T2) ERROR: received null value");
                error = true;
                return;
            }
            int nToRead = Int32.Parse(receivedCountString);
            while(nToRead > 0)
            {
                string receivedString = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
                if (receivedString == null)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("(T2) ERROR: received null value");
                    error = true;
                    return;
                }
                buffer.Add(receivedString);
                nToRead--;
            }

            received = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a example of output from the program above:

```
Please write something to send to the other task (write ';;;' to end)
aaa
The list now contains 1 lines
Please write something to send to the other task (write ';;;' to end)
bbb
The list now contains 2 lines
Please write something to send to the other task (write ';;;' to end)
ccc
The list now contains 3 lines
Please write something to send to the other task (write ';;;' to end)
ddd
The list now contains 4 lines
Please write something to send to the other task (write ';;;' to end)
;;;
(T1) waiting before starting...
(T2) waiting for connections...
received a incoming connection
(T1) Sending line count: 4
(T1) sending line: aaa
(T1) sending line: bbb
(T1) sending line: ccc
(T1) sending line: ddd
(T1) closing connection
(T2) ERROR: received null value
(T2) closing connection (error occurred)
Done.
```

I'm using Windows11 and Visual Studio 2019 to run the code (UWP project).

Comment: Is it possible your sender is closing the connection before the receiver can actually receive the data?

Comment: I checked this possibility putting a Sleep before the connection is disposed, but nothing seems to change: in addition, the listener waits until the connection is released, then complains.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to connect to the localhost. Have you enabled the local loopback? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/communication/interprocess-communication#loopback

Comment: Yep, I checked: using the tool I found that the interface have been opened before. Thank you for the clue :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I foudn the answer seeing other similar posts. In particular I found this resource, which is related with what I'm trying to do currently.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36500.uwp-linux-socket-communication-handling-communciation-in-the-backgroundtask.aspx

I tried to build a client on my local PC with C# in VS2019, and a server on my Linux server machine (I'm using ADA Cloud) in Python. Neither this worked at first time: the server went stuck waiting for a message... which the C# side shoud have been sent.

Here's my Server:

```py
#!/bin/bash

import socket
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("USAGE:\n\tserver.py <PORT_NO>")
        sys.exit(1)
HOST = socket.gethostname()
print( f"Hostname is {HOST}" )
PORTNO = int(sys.argv[1])
print( f"port set to {PORTNO}" )

print("opening socket connection...")
sk = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
print( f"trying to open server using \n\tHOST {HOST} \n\tPORTNO {PORTNO}" )
sk.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sk.bind( (HOST, PORTNO) )
sk.listen( 4 )
print("OK - listening")

print( "waiting connection..." )
new_socket, new_socket_addr = sk.accept( )
print( "Conenction received!" )

print("waiting for messages...")
data = new_socket.recv(1024)
print( f"received:\n\t{data}" )
new_socket.send(data)
print("Echo done")

new_socket.close()
sk.close()
print("closing...")
```

And here's my client:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows;
using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;

namespace UWPConsoleApp
{
    class UWPConsoleApp
    {
        static void Main(string[] argv)
        {
            string Host = "131.175.205.146";
            string Portno = "5000";

            Console.WriteLine("Trying to connect...");

            StreamSocket ss = new StreamSocket();
            ss.ConnectAsync(new HostName(Host), Portno).AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            Console.WriteLine($"Connection Estalished with HOST {Host} PORTNO {Portno}");

            Console.WriteLine("Sending data...");
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ss.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite());
            
            sw.Write("asdiaiHNIUNAHidsi uh aiudnhai i ish i");

            Console.WriteLine("Receiving data...");
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ss.InputStream.AsStreamForRead());
            sr.ReadToEnd();

            Console.WriteLine("OK! Closing...");
            sr.Dispose();
            sw.Dispose();
            ss.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that *the snippet in that website launched the Flush() every time the Write() is called*. Well, I tried... and it worked!

```cs
// before
sw.Write("asdiaiHNIUNAHidsi uh aiudnhai i ish i");

// after
sw.Write("asdiaiHNIUNAHidsi uh aiudnhai i ish i");
sw.Flush();
```

Well ... I tried to update the code above in this way, and... oh! It worked.

Here's the final version of the code:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Storage;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.Networking;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;

namespace UWPConsoleApp
{
    class UWPConsoleApp
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<String> toSend = new List<string>();
            bool end = false;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please write something to send to the other task (write ';;;' to end)");
                string s = Console.ReadLine();
                if (s != ";;;")
                {
                    toSend.Add(s);
                    Console.WriteLine($"The list now contains {toSend.Count} lines");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (toSend.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("WARNING: you may insert atleast one line before going on");
                        continue;
                    }
                    end = true;
                }
            }
            while (!end);

            List<string> received;
            Task[] tasks =
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
                {
                    ThreadSender ts = new ThreadSender();
                    ts.buffer = toSend;

                    Console.WriteLine("(T1) waiting before starting...");
                    Thread.Sleep(7500);

                    ts.SendInfos();
                } ),
                Task.Factory.StartNew( async () =>
                {
                    ThreadReceiver tr = new ThreadReceiver();
                    received = await tr.ReceiveInfos();
                } )
            };

            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class ThreadSender
    {
        // buffer di invio
        public List<String> buffer;

        // socket per l'invio dei dati
        private StreamSocket ss;

        public ThreadSender()
        {
            buffer = new List<string>();
            ss = new StreamSocket();
        }

        public async void SendInfos()
        {
            HostName hn = new HostName("localhost");
            await ss.ConnectAsync(hn, "3000");

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ss.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite());
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ss.InputStream.AsStreamForRead());

            Console.WriteLine($"(T1) Sending line count: {buffer.Count}");
            sw.WriteLine(buffer.Count.ToString());
            sw.Flush();
            foreach (string line in buffer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("(T1) sending line: {0}", line);
                sw.WriteLine(line);
                sw.Flush();
            }

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("(T1) closing connection");
            ss.Dispose();
            ss = null;
        }
    }

    class ThreadReceiver
    {
        // buffer di scrittura
        public List<String> buffer = new List<string>();

        private StreamSocketListener ssl;
        private bool received = false;
        private bool error = false;

        public ThreadReceiver()
        {
            ssl = new StreamSocketListener();
        }

        public async Task<List<string>> ReceiveInfos()
        {
            ssl.ConnectionReceived += onConnectionReceived;
            await ssl.BindServiceNameAsync("3000");

            Console.WriteLine("(T2) waiting for connections...");
            while (!received)
            {
                if (error)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("(T2) closing connection (error occurred)");
                    return null;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(2500);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("(T2) All Received! Closing...");
            return buffer;
        }

        public async void onConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("(T2) received a incoming connection");
            Thread.Sleep(2500);

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead());
            string receivedCountString = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
            if (receivedCountString == null)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("(T2) ERROR: received null value");
                error = true;
                return;
            }
            int nToRead = Int32.Parse(receivedCountString);
            
            Console.WriteLine($"(T2) Receiving {nToRead} messages...");
            while (nToRead > 0)
            {
                string receivedString = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
                if (receivedString == null)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("(T2) ERROR: received null value");
                    error = true;
                    return;
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine($"(T2) Received string: {receivedString}");
                buffer.Add(receivedString);
                nToRead--;
                Console.WriteLine($"Remaining {nToRead} messages");
            }

            received = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I